# valueOf() or parseInt() is not working for my code

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java and I'm trying to make a method that returns the sum of the digits of a number say: input = 123 --> returns 6. I'm using a String input (since I am also going to concatenate the String to itself by n times before getting the superDigit) so I needed to use a "String to Integer (not primitive)".

Compile Time Error: "The method valueOf(String, int) is undefined for the type superDigit

Am I missing a library here? Do I need to make my own "valueOf" method?

```
public String superDigit(String s, int n) {
    Integer newString = 0;
    //just in case the string is really really long
    for(int i = 0; i <= n ; ++i) { 
        newString = valueOf(s, 10);  //<-- this line has an error (stated above)
        setOutput(Integer.toString(firstOutput(newString)));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Use `Integer.valueOf()`

Comment: that means you are using (or trying to use, at least) a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: In Java, every method belongs to a class. If you call a method without mentioning which class or object of that class means the compiler assumes the method you are calling belongs to the current class. Which in this case, it isn't. You have to mention the name of the class `Integer`, like you did in the line that followed.

Comment: @RealSkeptic what about (static) imports?

Comment: I am going to make a small suggestion, you can find the last digit of a number using the modulo operator. ie. `int a = 123;` a%10 is equal to 3. To find the second digit you divide by 10. `a = a/10;` and now a%10 is equal to 2.

Comment: @Stultuske this was a comment, not an answer. I was trying to explain the source of the problem here. Obviously, there is no static import here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my error out.

Comment: @Turamarth Thanks. I didn’t notice that haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Specify the class where the `valueOf` is defined (use `Integer.valueOf` instead of `valueOf`)
2. Use a static import: `import static java.lang.Integer.valueOf;`. In this case you could use `valueOf` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code tries to use static method from Integer class. There are two approaches to write the call

1. By doing static imports in the class.
2. When you have to use static method use the *class name.static method* for invocation.

> valueOf method from the Integer wrapper class is static.

```
public String superDigit(String s, int n) {
    Integer newString = 0;
    //just in case the string is really really long
    for(int i = 0; i <= n ; ++i) { 
        newString = Integer.valueOf(s, 10);  //<-- Use Integer.valueOf
        setOutput(Integer.toString(firstOutput(newString)));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Compile Time Error: "The method valueOf(String, int) is undefined for the type superDigit

Interpretation: since the method name `valueOf` is not qualified by anything (e.g. a variable name or a class name) AND since you have not imported it using an `import static`, the compiler *expects* it to be a method declared or inherited by your `superDigit` class.  But your class apparently doesn't define a method that matches the expected signature.  Hence ... compilation error.

> Am I missing a library here? Do I need to make my own "valueOf" method?

That is difficult to say.

Based on the way you have used it, this `valueOf` method needs to produce a `String` from a `String` and an `int`, with no clues as to how the result should be produced.  (And your `firstOutput` method is equally opaque, though we can infer that it produces an integer ... somehow.)

Given that we don't know what this `valueOf` is supposed to do, we can't say for sure whether there is an existing method with that name that you can import, or whether you need to implement it for yourself.  I am *guessing* the latter.  But before you start implementing it, I think you need to review the code that you have written and work out what `valueOf` and `firstOutput` need to do in order to achieve the required end.

---

Alternatively, try looking at the methods in the `String` and `Character` APIs ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)).  Look at `String::charAt` and `Character::digit`.  Can you use those methods to build a solution?

Comment: Thanks. At first I was planning to use charAt but I thought the running time would be slower than this and the code will need more error handling. Thanks for the suggestion. I’ll try iterating from each elements as well next time. For now, I’m going to stick with the direct conversion of data types.

Comment: Well OK, but I would just point out a couple of things.  1) Efficiency doesn't matter in this context, and even if it did your intuition is wrong.  `Integer.valueOf` is a lot more expensive than `charAt`.  2) Just using `Integer.valueOf` doesn't fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that can get you the output that you are looking for:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String answer = App.superDigit(123);
        System.out.println(answer);

    }

    public static String superDigit(int num) {
        String numString = String.valueOf(num);
        String[] numArray = numString.split("");
        int answer = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < numArray.length; x++) {
          answer += Integer.parseInt(numArray[x]);
              }

        return String.valueOf(answer);

        }

}
```

Here is your output:

```
6
```

Lets talk through this problem. You are simply calling the static method "valueOf" but you are not calling a Wrapper class or the String class with the valueOf method. You have to call a class with the valueOf() method. In this case you would want to call Integer.valueOf() in your code. In the example I showed you however, we called String.valueOf(). But simply calling valueOf() without calling a class with the method will result in the error that you mentioned. Secondly, we can simply enter one argument into the method, which can be the digits that you want to work with, instead of entering a String. We can use the String.valueOf() method to turn the integer into a String, and then we can split it in an array. We can create an Integer called answer and add to it on each iteration through the array by converting each index into an Integer with the Integer.parseInt() method. Lastly, we can return the fully formatted String representation of the sum with the String.valueOf(answer); line.